# Extending an image (PIL/Pillow)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I can use the following code to draw a black strip (or rectangle) atop a base image:

```
base_width, base_height = img.size
background = Image.new('RGBA', (base_width, base_height/3),(0,0,0,146))
offset = (0,base_height/2)
img.paste(background,offset,mask=background)
```

Result:

[image]

But how do I extend the height of the image such that the said black strip appears attached below the image's bottom border, *outside the image itself*?

If I move the `offset` in my code above, the black strip can't move beyond the borders of the base image, so that's not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. Create a `new_img` that is `(base_width, base_height + background.height)` in size
2. Paste the original `img` into `new_img` at `(0, 0)`
3. Paste the `background` into `new_img` at `(0, base_height)`